# Proof verification about suprema of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $x$ be a real number such that $x:=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}=\sup(\{a_n : n\geq m\}$. Then for all $n\geq m$, we have that $a_n\leq x$ and if $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $M$ is an upper bound for $a_n$, then for all $n\geq m$, we have $M\geq a_n$. Also, for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y<x$, there exists an $n\geq m$ such that $y<a_n\leq x$.

Here is my attempt at a proof:

By definition, $x$ is the supremum of the set $\{a_n : n\geq m\}$, which means it is an upper bound for the set. So for every $n\geq m$, we have $a_n \leq x$. Also  by definition, for any $M$ that is an upper bound of the set, $x\leq M$, to which $a_n \leq x\leq M$ follows. Finally, by the definition of supremum, we have that for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists an $a_n\in \{a_n : n\geq m\}$ such that $a_n>x-\varepsilon$. So set $y=x-\varepsilon <x$ to obtain $a_n>y=x-\varepsilon$ and then $x\geq a_n >y$ follows.

I am self-studying real analysis so I just want to make sure I am making all of the correct steps and if I am constructing this proof right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine but writing needs improvements. You are given $y<x$ so 'set $y=x-\epsilon<x$' doesn't make sense. Instead, you should say let $\epsilon =x-y$. Then $\epsilon >0$ so there exists $n$ such that $a_n >x-\epsilon$. With this change your arguments are all OK.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it wrong if I set $y=x-\varepsilon$ instead of letting  $\varepsilon=x-y$?

Comment: @CSquared You are given  $y<x$ in the question. $y$ is not at your choice. But $\epsilon $ is of your choice. For any choice of $\epsilon$ you can use the definition of supremum to get an $n$ such that $a_n >x-\epsilon$.

Comment: ok. I'll keep that in mind. that makes more sense now.